# How to say it properly?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How can you say to a child not to pour water on you when she is taking a bath? My sister use the term don't wet me and it sounds off

Answer (score 1):

> Don't splash water *on* me! / Don't splash me *with* water! / **Don't splash me!** (if it's clear that water is meant)

If the water didn't reach you because you were far enough, you can say:

> Don't splash water *at* me!

As for the verb *to wet*, here is an example of how it can be used when talking about babies/young children:

> The baby has wetted/wet the bed (*urinated in bed*).

So, you are right. Your sister really doesn't mean "Don't wet me!"

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that a person is being splashed with water not urine. Water wets things just as urine does. I think it is still correct to say. Don’t wet me!  When someone intentionally sprays you with a garden hose, aren’t you getting wet? In this instance “ Don’t wet me!” fits. I think your sister may be correct.

Comment: "To wet [a person]" is uncommon. "Do not get me wet" I think might be closer to what you mean.